# puts выводит кракозябры

Tags: c++, строки

Только начал изучать операции над строками в с++ и столкнулся с проблемой вывода непонятных символов. Возможно это из-за указателей ( не совсем уверен что все правильно написал).Задание-разбить две строки на слова и получить массив, который содержит слова строки + распечатать первое слово.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
char s1[100];
char s2[100];
using namespace std;
char** Words(char *s) {
    int i = 0;
    char*p;
    char*np = NULL;
    char **m = new char*[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) *(m + i) = new char[100];
    char *delimeter = " ,.!?;:\n";
    p = strtok_s(s, delimeter, &np);
    while (p != NULL) {
        strcpy_s(*m, sizeof(*m), p);
        m++;
        p = strtok_s(NULL, delimeter, &np);
    }
    return m;
}

int main()
{
    char **p1;
    char **p2;
    gets_s(s1);
    gets_s(s2);
    p1 = Words(s1);
    puts(*p1);
    p2 = Words(s2);
    puts(*p2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ну вот for `(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) *(m + i) = new char[100];` когда в массиве всего 10 элементов. `char *delimeter = " ,.!?;:\n";` тоже не правильно. В `strcpy_s(*m, sizeof(*m), p);` sizeof применяется к указателю. Вся выделенная память утекает. Такое ощущение, что вы пишите на C.

Comment: @VTT `char *delimeter = " ,.!?;:\n"; тоже не правильно` -- только с точки зрения орфографии (если не придираться к const). Причём и у автора, и у вас :)

Comment: @PinkTux [Ни шагу без автокомплита](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eI9QH.jpg).